# Matplotlib imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am stuck with python and matplotlib imshow(). Aim is it to show a twodimensonal color map which represents three dimensions. 
My x-axis is represented by an array'TG'(93 entries). My y-axis is a set of arrays dependend of my 'TG' To be precise we have 93 different arrays with the length of 340. My z-axis is also a set of arrays depended of my 'TG' equally sized then y (93x340).
Basically what I have is a set of two-dimensonal measurements which I want to plot in color dependend on a third array. Is there a clever way to do that. I was trying to find out on my own first, but all I found is that most common is the problem with just a z-plane(two-dimensonal plot). So I have two matrices of the order of (93x340) and one array(93). Do you know a helpful advise.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Is there any code?  plz

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail on your specific problem, it's hard to guess what is the best way to represent your data. I am going to give an example, hopefully it is relevant.

Suppose we are collecting height and weight of a group of people. Maybe the index of the person is your first dimension, and the height and weight depends on who it is. Then one way to represent this data is use height and weight as the x and y axes, and plot each person as a dot in that two dimensional space.

In this example, the person index doesn't really have much meaning, thus no color is needed.